# Can you ise celery with redislite on an Azure App Service

Tags: python-3.x, redis, azure-web-app-service, celery, gunicorn

Using gunicorn, I am trying to deploy a dash flask app with long callbacks that use celery to process background tasks (python 3.9). I have this fully functional on my local machine using redislite and start the app by running a startup script that does the following:

1. Starts the celery app with 3 workers
2. Runs the app using gunicorn on 0.0.0.0:8080

As the redis functionality is a separate add on for Azure, I am trying to deploy using redislite instead.

I have already setup the app service for continuous development on my github repo, and have entered startup.sh into the startup configuration field during setup. However, I am unable to get the container to start.

Is there a way to deploy a celery app that uses a redislite backend on an Azure app service? If so, what would be the correct way to start this app?

I can provide more details on the error messages, but I am curious if this is even possible and what the correct way to start this is. Maybe I am doing it wrong.

Comment: Hi, Did you figure out the solution to this? I am also trying something similar.

Comment: Yes and no. It was not possible using Azure app service so we ended up using Docker and deploying a Docker container instance on Azure.